# Why JAXB map to JAXBElement instead of specified types?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

why jaxb not generate to specified types? It generated generic List<JAXBElement<?>> instead of generating to specified types.

The case is I used xjc to convert my xsd to java Obj,

my xsd,

```
<xs:complexType name="InputType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="add" type="AddInputType"/>
        <xs:element name="get" type="GetInputType"/>
        <xs:element name="del" type="DeleteInputType"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

generated java class,

```
public class InputType {

@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "add", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "get", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "del", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> addOrGetOrDel;

public List<JAXBElement<?>> getAddOrGetOrDel() {
    if (addOrGetOrDel == null) {
        addOrGetOrDel = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
    }
    return this.addOrGetOrDel;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your xsd example and could not reproduce your output using xjc of java jdk version 1.7.0_04. Please state your java version, the complete xsd and how you call xjc. My test generated specified types (e.g. AddInputType.class and so on).

Comment: Did you find a solution?